# Error with installing WRGprettyPhoto BlogEngine.NET Extension

Tags: blogengine.net

Hello Everyone i'm facing a problem with my BlogEngine.NET with some extensions, i tried to find a reasonable reason for it but i failed take for example this extension  http://wellroundedgeek.com/post/2010/05/26/WRGprettyPhoto.aspx whenever upload it to the extenstion folder i get this error page:

http://i48.tinypic.com/73m8wi.png

Note i'm hosting my blog on asphostportal but my domain is from godaddy

please help me out with this ...